# Can we have the flag counter show remaining flags, not total flags?

Tags: feature-request

I believe this is a new feature so I'm hoping for once I'll have an issue that isn't a duplicate.

I've noticed the review counter is back on the bar, which is great. I have also noticed that it now hides the posts you have made a decision on, even better!

What it does right now is show the total amount of flags that are available instead of those that are not yet handled by myself. Can this be switched?

[image]

Comment: Its showing *8* to me, despite just the one remaining in the queue :( This really needs fixing.